# How to add Field to a mongoDB database in a Symfony2/SonataAdmin project?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm working in a BackOffice Symfony2.3 with MongoDB and SonataAdmin.

I'm trying to add a new field to one of the documents.

I've just added one parameter

```
     /**
     * @var integer
     * @MongoDB\Int
     */
      protected $price_teste;
```

I used the console to add the getters and the setters in the class.

Finally, I've changed the admin class in sonata to have in the form the new champ

```
 /**
 * @param ListMapper $listMapper
 */
  protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
  {
    $listMapper
     //...  
     ->add('price_teste')
    //....
```

When I go to the BackOffice I see the new champ but when I try to update the instance, the value disappears. So I imagine it's not being persisted to the database.

There any other procedure I'm forgetting to do to add a new parameter to an existing document in the project?

Comment: Try to run `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:cache:clear-metadata`

Comment: No changes in the problem :(